# Ubuntu 20.04 resolution locked at 1024x768

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

I have a 4k LG monitor and it normally works just fine with Ubuntu. Today (3/15/2021) I installed updates, changed the audio settings from SPDIF output to the monitor, and rebooted. Now I have no resolution options other than 1024x768 and I can't figure out how to get them back. My monitor is no longer identified as a "LG 27 inch monitor" (it is 32", but linux always thinks it is 27").

Secure boot is set up correctly and I tried uninstalling the Nvidia 460 driver and installing the 450 version and that did not help.

xrandr output:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

intel i7-6950x, Nvidia 1080 Ti

I finally got 4k resolution back after switching to the Nouveau display driver, but now Software & Updates shows this:

[image]

And it does not allow me to re-install a Nvidia driver.  What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem today. Not sure what the answer is just yet, but this has happened to me a couple of times in the past and in the end it was a delay between a kernel patch being pushed and the corresponding Nvidia driver push. Normally I leave any updates for a week, but didn't notice kernel level ones in this update and applied them. For now, I have booted to the previous kernel and all works well.

Hopefully an updated Nvidia patch will arrive soon!.

Comment: HI, perhaps tell the OP how to boot in the previous kernel might enhance your answer ;)